# Android SQLite wont read specific values

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm facing a problem trying to read from the internal SQLite database (Android).

this is my code of the local database:

```
public class LocalDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database";
static final int DATABASE_VER = 2;

static final String PROFILES_TABLE_NAME = "profiles";
static final String KEY_ID = "node_id";
static final String KEY_USERID = "user_id";
static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
static final String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";
static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "lastname";
static final String KEY_STUDY = "study";
static final String KEY_PROFESSION = "profession";
static final String KEY_KNOWS = "knows";
static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
static final String KEY_POINTS = "points";
static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
static final String KEY_DOB = "dob";
static final String KEY_CREATED = "created";

public LocalDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VER);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CreateProfileTable = "CREATE TABLE " + PROFILES_TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                                KEY_USERID + " TEXT," +
                                KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," +
                                KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT," +
                                KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT," +
                                KEY_STUDY + " TEXT," + 
                                KEY_PROFESSION + " TEXT," +
                                KEY_KNOWS + " TEXT," +
                                KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT," +
                                KEY_STATUS + " TEXT," +
                                KEY_POINTS + " INTEGER," +
                                KEY_GENDER + " TEXT," +
                                KEY_DOB + " TEXT," +
                                KEY_CREATED + "TEXT)";

    db.execSQL(CreateProfileTable);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PROFILES_TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);

}

public void addUserProfile(String userID, String email, String firstname, String lastname, String study, String profession, String knows,
        String location, String status, int points, String gender, String DOB, String created){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues params = new ContentValues();

    params.put(KEY_USERID, userID);
    params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    params.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, firstname);
    params.put(KEY_LASTNAME, lastname);
    params.put(KEY_STUDY, study);
    params.put(KEY_PROFESSION, profession);
    params.put(KEY_KNOWS, knows);
    params.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);
    params.put(KEY_STATUS, status);
    params.put(KEY_POINTS, points);
    params.put(KEY_GENDER, gender);
    params.put(KEY_DOB, DOB);
    params.put(KEY_CREATED, created);

    db.insert(PROFILES_TABLE_NAME, null, params);
    db.close();


}

public ContentValues getUserProfile(){

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + PROFILES_TABLE_NAME;
    ContentValues userProfile = new ContentValues();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    c.moveToFirst();

    if(c.getCount()>0){

        userProfile.put(KEY_USERID, c.getString(1));
        userProfile.put(KEY_EMAIL, c.getString(2));
        userProfile.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, c.getString(3));
        userProfile.put(KEY_LASTNAME, c.getString(4));
        userProfile.put(KEY_STUDY, c.getString(5));
        userProfile.put(KEY_PROFESSION, c.getString(6));
        userProfile.put(KEY_KNOWS, c.getString(7));
        userProfile.put(KEY_LOCATION, c.getString(8));
        userProfile.put(KEY_STATUS, c.getString(9));
        userProfile.put(KEY_POINTS, c.getString(10));
        userProfile.put(KEY_GENDER, c.getString(11));
        userProfile.put(KEY_DOB, c.getString(12));
        userProfile.put(KEY_CREATED, c.getString(13));

    }

    c.close();
    db.close();

    return userProfile;

}
```

}

the problem is that after i insert the data into the database (using add user profile) when i'm trying to read it using (getUserProfile) all the field except user_id and email are null, i checked the params variable at addUserProfile and it's getting the correct values

can someone explain me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any errors in the `LogCat`?  You can also use `<sdk>/tools/adb shell` and run `sqlite3` and perform queries on the database to check if it contains what you are expecting.

Comment: @techiServices nope, no logcat error...

Comment: ok, use adb and run a manual query to check that the columns have been populated.

Comment: @techiServices cant access to /data/data chmod say's that operation cannot be done

Comment: Are you debugging on a device or emulator?  You need to use the emulator unless your device is rooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you entered some values initially(probably only for the userid and email fields) and later didn't clear the app's data so the database is reconstructed again(and you continue to have those previously entered values in the database). In this case even if you entered new values you'll build the `ContentValues` object(containing the results) only for the first data row from the results `Cursor` *c*(you do `c.moveToFirst();`). The first values are the values that only have the userid and the email and you get `null` for everything else.

Also you have a typo in your sql creation string `CreateProfileTable`, it should be like this:

```
...KEY_CREATED + " TEXT)";
```

Modify the `CreateProfileTable` string like above and then uninstall and reinstall your app.

Comment: i reset the tables on each run using db.delete method that's delete the table, BTW i change the typo and its still not working

Comment: @user1396033 How exactly do you delete the table with `db.delete`, I don't see this in your code? Try to **uninstall** the app and then reinstall it. Also I hope you're not adding any values to the database beside using the method `addUserProfile`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a single space.  `KEY_CREATED + "TEXT)";` should be `KEY_CREATED + " TEXT)";`

I put all your code into eclipse with a test activity and I was able to get it to work fine.

I put the following code in my activity to test it (after deleting the database with the bad table caused by the above typo using adb) and everything works as expected.

```
    LocalDatabase db = new LocalDatabase(this);
    db.addUserProfile("01", "email", "firstname", "lastname", "study",
            "profession", "knows", "location", "status", 1,
            "gender", "DOB", "created");

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv = db.getUserProfile();
```

cv contains the expected values.  If your still having problems let us know.

If your having problems deleting the old database, try uping the version number in `DATABASE_VER` in your LocalDatabase Class.